# Let me choose a different notification sound specific to the app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, android-app, audio

I love having different notification sounds for various apps on my phone so that when I get a notification I know exactly what app it came from, and thus exactly what kind of notification it is. It lets me prioritize the notification in my head so I know how important it is to get to my phone and check it.

Unfortunately, the Stack Exchange app does not have the ability to select a custom notification sound, so it uses the default notification sound for the device and gets mixed into all the other apps which *also* don't let me select a custom sound.

I think allowing users to choose a custom notification sound for the app is a great improvement. I really love when apps let me choose one rather than forcing me to use the default.

Comment: So you're saying you'd prioritize notifications from SE if you knew it was a SE app notification? Good mod. :P

Comment: The vibrate alert already seems to be subtly different, I can distinguish mails from SE notifications there. I find this pretty convenient, so making this customizable sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an excellent idea and it's implemented in the app as of version 0.1.90 coming out in the next few hours.

In implementing this I realized my old beloved text noise from the original version of Android called "Captain's Log" still exists, and I am insanely happy right now, so thanks :)

Comment: [Is this the sound you mean](http://dc599.4shared.com/img/1965834004/1d727a53/dlink__2Fdownload_2FNL7FVpLE_3Ftsid_3D20140124-002032-db7cc1fa/preview.ogg?sId=b2hzNXNyMi1AgYop)? No android for me so just curious. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, minus the echoing of the initial beep. It was the default sound on the G1 (or the sound I picked, can't remember) so getting the notification from your comment made me think I had a text message on my no longer functioning old phone!

Comment: oh, phone ghost... hope I didn't cause you a heart attack! :-D