# Stop calling me, Stack Exchange, I need my space! (aka let me change the vibrate on the Android app)

Tags: feature-request, notifications, android-app

## Background

The current Android app gives notifications in the form of a [customisable sound](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217007/let-me-choose-a-different-notification-sound-specific-to-the-app) and a non-customisable vibration.

The current vibration is exactly the same as the phone call notification<sup>1</sup> which primes me to receive a phone call (I'll admit it; I don't really like being called).

<sup>1: on my phone at least: Samsung Galaxy S3, no other notifications other than phone calls and Stack Exchange notifications come through like this</sup>

## Feature request

Would it be possible to customise the vibration pattern that we receive with notifications?

Comment: Which device are you using? On my Nexus 5, the app notification causes two short buzzes, which seems to be standard across all notifications on the device. A phone call is a very long buzz.

Comment: @StevenV Interesting, for me the SE notification is a single long buzz (same as the phone call but the phone call repeats). I'm using a Galaxy S3

Comment: I was tinkering with a Galaxy S5 a few days ago and I noticed the notification vibrate was different. Maybe Samsung changed the default notification vibrate pattern? It is the same vibrate pattern for other notifications on the device?

Comment: @StevenV Texts come through as 2 short blasts. I think most other notifications do as well. Nothing else on the phone (apart from calls) comes through as a long vibrate

Comment: Do you know of any app that lets you modify the vibration pattern? I'd like to steal their interface, if possible. Most apps I see have the same on/off switch we have.

Comment: @Kasra interesting question.  The ones I have installed don'tbut they have a different vibration pattern to SE. However,  this app claims to set vibration patterns for different apps (although the free version doesn't recognise stack exchange app); . https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itchyfingerzfree.vybe&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dset+custom+vibrate+android

Comment: @RichardTingle We can definitely do custom vibrations, I just don't know how to present it to the user (you send it to the OS by a series of "vibrate for this many ms, pause for this many"), I don't know why the current code would have a different vibration than other apps though.

Comment: @Kasra Ah, I see. What I have seen (e.g. in  [vybr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.itchyfingerzfree.vybe&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dset+custom+vibrate+android))  is a touch based recording of a pattern but that seems like overkill, my 2 cents would just be for 5 or 6 options for the user to choose from (similar to the sound selector)